# Android hide image from user gallery

Tags: android, web, gallery, phonegap-build, file-transfer

i'm using the following phonegap build plugin:

> com.chanthu.evri.gcs-file-transfer version="1.0.0"

to download images on devices. The download is ok but the images are visible in user's standard gallery myApp folder. How can i save the images without creating such a gallery ?

The path I use to save them is:

> cdvfile://localhost/persistent/myApp/

The path on the android device become:

> /storage/sdcard0/myApp/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create a .nomedia file and put it into myApp folder using the below code.

```
  try
    {
        File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/myApp");
        if(!dir.exists())
        {
            dir.mkdirs();
            String filenameForNoMedia4 = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+".nomedia";
            FileOutputStream outForNoMedia4 = new FileOutputStream(filenameForNoMedia4);

        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

    }
```

But for this you need add a permission to androidManifest.xml file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: This answer is old but adding `.nomedia` really does the trick. On a side note, please make sure to add the `.nomedia` file BEFORE you write any images on a directory. Adding the `.nomedia` file after the images are scanned, may require a phone reboot / directory rescan for it to work

Answer (score 2):

Android is Linux so whatever works to hide files and folders in Linux works on Android, too.

If you want to hide *all* the data in a folder, just add a `.nomedia` file to that folder. If, however, you want to hide a specific file, just prepend a `.` to it's name.

```
FOLDER 1 
|
-- .file1.txt
-- file2.txt
-- FOLDER 2
   |
   -- .nomedia
   -- file3.txt
   -- file4.txt
```

In the above scenario, all the content under `FOLDER 2` is hidden and only `file1` from `FOLDER 1` is hidden.

Answer (score 1):

Create a .nomedia file and put this in the folder where you store images.

This file hides the folder and its ages from showing up in gallery